# False Unique Particle Attribution (UPA)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

Given the following two schemas

(Root)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:someNs="first" 
            xmlns:someOtherNs="second"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            elementFormDefault="unqualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
            version="1.0" 
            targetNamespace="first">
  <xsd:import namespace="second" schemaLocation="./child.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="employee" type="someNs:fullpersoninfo" />

  <xsd:complexType name="personinfo">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="fullpersoninfo">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="someNs:personinfo">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:group ref="someOtherNs:Child" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

and (child)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="someId-1" 
           targetNamespace="second" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:someOtherNs="second"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="second">

  <xs:element name="ChildElement" type="ChildElement"
              nillable="false" />

  <xs:complexType name="ChildElement">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:group name="Child">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="ChildElement" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded"
              namespace="##other" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>

</xs:schema>
```

a Unique particle attribution should not be present as the child uses `elementFormDefault="qualified"` and the root uses `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`. However, when run through Java's xjc, it is not possible to use the generated classes as the annotations on the classes seems to be insufficient - at least it seems. How can the UPA be avoided?

The error in question is as follows:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 41; cos-nonambig:"second":ChildElement and WC[##other:"first"] (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

Comment: For which declaration are you receiving a UPA error?  Please paste the exact error message into your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error message quoted indicates that the schema processor is interpreting `<xs:any namespace="##other" .../>` as allowing any element not in namespace `first`.  That is, it's treating the group reference as if it were a simple macro expansion, and then creating the model group components in the context of the root schema document (where `##other` would refer to any namespace other than the target namespace `first`), rather than creating them in the context of the child schema document (where `##other` would refer to any namespace other than the target namespace `second`).

A case could probably be made that [section 3.10.2 of the XSD 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-openness) requires that `##other` be interpreted in the child.xsd context:  when `namespace="##other"`, the value of the {namespace constraint} property on the wildcard component is described as "a pair of `not` and the ·actual value· of the targetNamespace [attribute] of the `<schema>` ancestor element information item if present, otherwise ·absent·" -- for an `xs:any` element in child.xsd, that targetNamespace attribute has the value `second`, not `first`.

A case could probably be made the other way:  the spec is also clear that references to named model groups are not visible at the component level, that the scope of a local element declaration is determined by the location of the model-group reference, not the location of the model-group definition, etc., etc.  Under those circumstances, it might seem positively irrational for the XSD spec to mean that `##other` here should not have the interpretation "any namespace except `first`".

On the whole, I lean toward the first interpretation, but I doubt very much that it would be possible to persuade the creators of your tool to change their interpretation of the spec:  the rules for expansion of named model groups are too confusing and involve too much hand-waving to persuade anyone easily that their interpretation is wrong.

[Oops.  The following alleged 'workaround' is not a workaround at all:  it's just another clearer way of eliciting the behavior your processor is currently exhibiting.  Sorry about that.]

One workaround:  add a named model group declaration to your root schema document, and refer to that one, not to the one in child.xsd.  So add this to the root schema document:

```
<xs:group name="Child">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="someOtherNs:ChildElement" 
                minOccurs="0" 
                maxOccurs="1" />
    <xs:any processContents="lax" 
            minOccurs="0" 
            maxOccurs="unbounded"
            namespace="##other" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

and change the reference from

```
<xsd:group ref="someOtherNs:Child" />
```

to

```
<xsd:group ref="someNs:Child" />
```

[End of non-working 'workaround'.  Now, let's try again.]

One way to work around your problem, if you really want your tool to interpret the wildcard in the `fullpersoninfo` type as allowing any element not in the `second` namespace, would be to move the type `fullpersoninfo` into the `second` namespace.  To keep `address` etc. in the `first` namespace, define a model group with those in the `first` namespace:

```
<xs:group name="additional-person-info">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="address" ... />
    ...
```

Declare `fullpersoninfo` in the `second` namespace:

```
<xsd:complexType name="fullpersoninfo">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="someNs:personinfo">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:group ref="someNs:additional-person-info"/>
        <xsd:group ref="someOtherNs:Child" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Refer to `fullpersoninfo` from the declaration for `employee` in the usual way:

```
<xsd:element name="employee" type="someOtherNs:fullpersoninfo" />
```

A different approach is called for if you decide that you really don't want an element like this to be valid:

```
<employee xmlns="first" xmlns:x="second">
  <firstname>Andrea</firstname>
  <lastname>Doria</lastname>
  <address/>
  <city/>
  <country/>
  <firstname>Andrew</firstname>
  <lastname>Carnegie</lastname>
</employee>
```

You might decide that you actually prefer it if the wildcard matches anything not in the `first` namespace -- but in that case, `{second}ChildElement` matches the wildcard, and you don't need to mention it in the content model at all.

You might decide that what you want it to match is anything not declared in the current version of the schema -- but for that, you'd need XSD 1.1 awareness in your tool.  And if you had 1.1 awareness, the content model you've got wouldn't be rejected (although it still might have an interpretation that surprised you).

Comment: C. M. Sperberg-McQueen, thanks for the quite elaborate explanation. However, as I see it - the only way for me to avoid this is to go with XSD 1.1. The thing is that I'm pretty much bound to the existing schemas as what I've presented is an extract from another standard that I'm to  follow - the EPCIS standard 1.0.1 (http://www.gs1.org/gsmp/kc/epcglobal/epcis/epcis_1_0_1-standard-20070921.pdf) - section 9.1.

As far as I can see - the presented schemas reflects what is required when extending the standard. However, it seems more like a tooling problem to me (XJC being the sinner)